# What would be the fastest way to sort an array of people by age?

Tags: algorithm, sorting

There's an array of structures

```
struct
{
string name;
string 2nd_name;
int age; // 0 to 150
}
```

Maximum array's length is 10^8.

I know I could use mergesort/quicksort and all the others well known algorithms, however I'd like to know if It's possible to add something else that would speed up the sorting.

Comment: Do you have a certain rule of rearranging the structs?

Comment: You could try counting sort: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort

Answer (score 6, accepted):

People's age is somewhat different than arbitrary integers for sorting: it has a very small number of possible distinct values (all people's ages are between 0 and 150). So the quickest way to sort it would be to allocate 151 linked lists (let's call them buckets) and put each person's data structure in the bucket according to his/her age:

```
bucket[person->age].add(person)
```

Comment: (and counting sort is indeed the generic implementation)

Comment: I'm not convinced this is faster than a good quick sort implementation though. Linked lists have their overhead, and `150 > log2(10^8)`.

Comment: @IVlad a linked list has a constant overhead. An array list hase a better overhead yet.

Answer (score 4):

First, note that even if the struct  is very big (i.e. long names) you do not need to use a file system sort, you can use an in-memory sort, because

```
# elements * 8 ~= 762 MB (most modern systems have enough memory for that)
             ^
        key(age) + pointer to struct requires 8 bytes in 32 bits system
```

It is important to minimize the disk accesses - because disks are not random access, and disk accesses are MUCH slower then RAM accesses.

Now, use a sort of your choice on that  - and avoid using disk for the sorting process.

Some possibilities of sorts (on RAM) for this case are:

- Standard quicksort or merge-sort
- [Bucket sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bucket_sort) can also be applied here, since the rage is limited to [0,150]
- [Radix sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort) (For the same reason, radix sort will need ceil(log_2(150)) ~= 8 iterations