# Preferred Sorting For People Based On Their Age

Tags: algorithm, sorting

Suppose we have 1 million entries of an object 'Person' with  two fields 'Name', 'Age'. The problem was to sort the entries based on the 'Age' of the person.

I was asked this question in an interview. I answered that we could use an array to store the objects and use quick sort as that would save us from using additional space but interviewer told that memory was not a factor.

My question is what would be the factor that would decide which sort to use?

Also what would be the preferred way to store this?

In this scenario does any sorting algorithm have an advantage over another sorting algorithm and would result in a better complexity?

Comment: Usually in such interview questions your 'questions' are more important than your answers. For eg, are all the ages integers? what is the range of values the ages can take? What are the constraints on memory? How often the data gets queried or updated? Hint: There may be a possibility of bucket sort or counting sort.

Comment: Since age will be in the range 0 - 120 (or even 150 for that matter), you can do it faster using counting sort.

Comment: @greybeard You could potentially use Radix sort if `Name` is of fixed length otherwise use any comparison-based sort first and pass it on to the Counting Sort Algorithm. Since it's stable, your order will be preserved.

Comment: @greybeard I never affirmed that counting sort can do that, read my comment again. I suggested to first sort by Name and then by Age (using counting sort). If you want to know the "how" of these two steps as well, you can easily google them up.

Comment: @greybeard Quite a stunt you pulled there, deleting all your previous comments. If you knew the method all this time, why didn't you explain it then? There's no point of boasting about your experience, if at the end of the day, you are not able to help OP or anyone who read this thread.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13109664/what-would-be-the-fastest-way-to-sort-an-array-of-people-by-age) Stackoverflow link may be useful to you.

The answers above are sufficient but i would like to add some more information from the link above.

I am copying some information from the answers in, the link above, over here.

We should note that even if the fields in the Object are very big (i.e. long names) you do not need to use a file system sort, you can use an in-memory sort, because

```
# elements * 8 ~= 762 MB (most modern systems have enough memory for that)
             ^
        key(age) + pointer to struct requires 8 bytes in 32 bits system
```

It is important to minimize the disk accesses - because disks are not random access, and disk accesses are MUCH slower then RAM accesses.

Now, use a sort of your choice on that  - and avoid using disk for the sorting process.

Some possibilities of sorts (on RAM) for this case are:

- Standard quicksort or merge-sort (Which you had already thought of)
- [Bucket sort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13109664/what-would-be-the-fastest-way-to-sort-an-array-of-people-by-age) can also be applied here, since the rage is limited to [0,150] (Which others have specified here under the name Count Sort)
- [Radix sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort) (For the same reason, radix sort will need ceil(log_2(150)) ~= 8 iterations

I wanted to point out the memory aspect in case you may encounter the same question but may need to answer it taking the memory constraints into consideration. In fact your constraints are even less(10^6 compared to the 10^8 in the other question).

As for the matter of storing it -

The quickest way to sort it would be to allocate 151 linked lists/vector (let's call them buckets or whatever you may depending on the language you prefer) and put each person's data structure in the bucket according to his/her age(all people's ages are between 0 and 150):

```
bucket[person->age].add(person)
```

As others have pointed out Bucket Sort is going to be the better option for you.

*In fact the beauty of bucket sort is that if you have to perform any operation on ranges of ages(like from 10-50 years of age) you can partition your bucket sizes according to your requirements(like have varied bucket range for each bucket).*

I repeat again i have copied the information from the answers in the link given above, but i believe they might be useful to you.

Answer (score 3):

If the array has *n* elements, then quicksort (or, actually, any comparison-based sort) is [*Ω(n log(n))*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_sort#Lower_bound_for_the_average_number_of_comparisons).

Here, though, it looks like you have here an alternative to comparison-based sorting,  since you need to sort only on age. Suppose there are *m* distinct ages. In this case, [Counting Sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort), will be *Θ(m + n)*. For the specifics of your question, assuming that age is in years, *m* is much smaller than *n*, and you can do this in linear time.

The implementation is trivial. Simply create an array of, say, 200 entries (200 being an upper bound on the age). The array is of linked lists. Scan over the people, and place each person in the linked list in the appropriate entry. Now, just concatenate the lists according to the positions in the array.

Answer (score 2):

Different sorting algorithms perform at different complexities, yes. Some use different amounts of space. And in practice, real performance with the same complexity varies too.
http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/computersciencetheory/sortcomp.html

There're different ways to set up a quicksort's partition method that could have an effect for ages. Shell sorts can have different gap settings that perform better for certain types of input. But maybe your interviewer was more interested in you thinking about 1 million people having a lot of duplicate ages; which might mean you want a 3-way quicksort, or as suggested in comments a counting sort.

Answer (score 2):

This is an interview question, so I guess interviewee's answer is more important than correct sorting algorithm. Your problem is sorting array of `Object` with field age is integer. Age has some special properties:

1. **integer:** there are some sorting algorithms specially design for integer.
2. **finite:** you know maximum age of people, right? For example that will be 200.

I will list some sorting algorithm for this problem with advantages and disadvantages that suitable enough in one interview session:

1. **Quick sort:** complexity is **O(NLogN)** and can apply to any data set. Quicksort is the fastest sort that using compare operator between two elements. Biggest disadvantage of quicksort is quicksort isn't stable. That means two objects equal in age doesn't maintain order after sorting.
2. **Merge sort**: complexity is **O(NLogN)**. Little bit slower than quicksort but this is a stable sort. Also this algorithm can apply to any data set.
3. **radix sort**: complexity is **O(w*n)**, with n is size of your list and w is maximum length of number of digits in your dataset. For example: length of 12 is 3, length of 154 is 3. So if people's age maximum is 99, complexity should be **O(2*n)**. This algorithm just can apply to integer or string.
4. **Counting sort** complexity is **O(m+n)**. With n is size of your list and m is number of distinct ages. This algorithm just can apply to integer.

Because we are sorting milion of entries and all values are integer stand in range `0 .. 200` so ton of duplicate values. So **counting sort** is the best fit with complexity `O(200 + N)`, with N ~= 1,000,000. 200 is not much.

Answer (score 1):

If you assume that you have finite number of different values of age (usually people are not older then 100) then you could use
counting sort (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort). You would be able to sort in linear time.

Comment: Please explain how to do a counting sort with `two fields 'Name', 'Age'` - can you do a stable sort if the objects had been sorted by name to begin with?